# What is the meaning of "close it out" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

> In the late 19th century, European coffee and grain exchanges took the next step and made the clearing
>   house a counterparty in all transactions. 
>   This meant that in case of a default, the house would still make full payment, collecting as much funds as possible from the defaulting party
>   and drawing on a fund the members of the exchange had contributed to. The further adoption of this system however was hindered by the notion of moral hazard; members with a high credit rating
>   didn’t want to be supporting the less creditworthy ones.
>   The moral hazard in this is that participants may be encouraged to take more risks in trading since
>   they share only in a part of the losses. In other words, it might sometimes be cheaper for a trading
>   member to default on a position than to **close it out**.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that one of the expectations of StackExchange is that you explain clearly the source of your confusion, and demonstrate your initial attempts at research. Did you try a web search or dictionary lookup on the phrase? What is your best guess as to what it means? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Close it out** means to meet contractual obligations. A futures contract is:

> an agreement traded on an organized exchange to buy or sell assets,
>   especially commodities or shares, at a fixed price but to be delivered
>   and paid for later.
>
> The primary difference between options and futures is that options
>   give the holder the right to buy or sell the underlying asset at
>   expiration, while *the holder of a futures contract is obligated to
>   fulfill the terms of his contract.* In real life, the actual delivery
>   rate of the underlying goods specified in futures contracts is very
>   low as the hedging or speculating benefits of the contracts can be had
>   largely without actually holding the contract until expiry and
>   delivering the good. For example, if you were long in a futures
>   contract, you could go short in the same type of contract to offset
>   your position. This serves to exit your position, much like selling a
>   stock in the equity markets closes a trade.

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/futures.asp)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Financial Times Lexicon](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=closeout), a **closeout** is defined as

> When goods are sold cheaply in a sale.

A **default** means that someone is unable or fails to repay a debt.  An example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_(finance)):

> for example when a home buyer fails to make a mortgage payment, or when a corporation or government fails to pay a bond which has reached maturity.

So the implication here is that the financial structure of this arrangement made it more financially prudent for financial entities or individuals to *default* on their debt obligations, or fail to pay, rather than to *close out*, or sell their assets at a cheap price.

The "moral hazard" being described is the notion that this arrangement would lead financially self-interested parties to behave in a way that would not benefit the economic system as a whole, and could lead the structure to a downward spiral.

Comment: Except they’re not selling at a cheap price they owe more money than they have.  I might only have 100 and owe 500.  I could just default and have them take my 100 paying the rest from the fund instead of going into debt for 400.

Comment: @Jim either way closing out means you settle your debts and assets for what they're worth on the market, whereas defaulting means failure to meet contractual obligations.  I feel like that's the pertinent distinction in the question.